# Cannot Utilize GPU on Remote Server with Jupyter Notebooks in PyCharm

Tags: python, tensorflow, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, gpu

I'm currently facing an issue where I cannot utilize the GPU on a remote server while working with Jupyter Notebooks in PyCharm. I am able to successfully connect to the remote server and run my **Jupyter Notebook** within **PyCharm**. However, when I try to execute code that requires GPU usage, it seems to be defaulting to the CPU instead.

***Problem***

I recently created a Conda environment and installed TensorFlow following the instructions in the official TensorFlow pip installation tutorial. When I run the following command in the terminal of the created environment (tfnuwan), I can see the GPU being utilized:

```
python3 -c "import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))"
```

Afterwards, I created a new kernel for Jupyter Notebooks using the following command:

```
python -m ipykernel install --user --name=tfnuwan --display-name="tfnuwan"
```

I then switched to the tfnuwan kernel and ran the same code that I executed in the terminal:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))
```

However, this time, the GPU was not detected.

I would greatly appreciate any solutions or suggestions to resolve this issue.

Comment: Maybe you have two different Tensorflow versions. Check `tf.config.__file__` in both cases?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. They have same tf versions.

Comment: I meant a detailed comparison, like printing the actual path of the imported module `print(tf.__file__)`

Comment: Hi @Nuwan Abeynayake, You may need to open the jupyter notebook in the same environment where you have setup Tensorflow GPU. Creating a new kernel will overwrite the configuration. Please have a look at this [link](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install/kernel_install.html#kernels-for-different-environments) for the reference.